# "Authentication is required to refresh the system sources"

Tags: system

Every so often, I get the following popup in Elementary OS:

"Authentication is required to refresh the system sources"

I enter my SUDO password, but it won't take it.  What password do I use?  Is this just a bug?

Thanks!

Jim
elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behavior on a fully up to date instance of Loki. On returning to a desktop which has been unattended all night, after login i am presented with the prompt to enter credentials to update system sources. My sudo password is rejected. I have no problem closing the prompt window & no other issues with the system (e.g., app store / apt-get updates etc) have any issue with my credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I ran all updates from the Terminal window, rebooted, and now I can access the shared drive. Perhaps something had gotten stepped on, and an update fixed it.

Hopefully this has fixed the other issue as well (the "Authentication is required" prompt).

Update:  The "Authentication is Required to refresh the system sources" window popped up again.  Problem not yet solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chmod +s /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
```

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information so that it is simple enough for someone with zero technical knowledge to easily understand. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same after installing updates. I performed another reboot and the popup is now gone.

Comment: The popup doesn't happen very often - maybe three times per month.  And I have rebooted, yet the popup returns a bit later.  So far, all I can do is close the popup by hitting the 'x'.

I thought about installing updates - not from the Updates icon, but from the terminal; in other words, all available updates.  That fixed an issue I had on my Mint computer.  I'll try that.

Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Mine returned as well. I reviewed the Other Software tab in Software & Updates and removed the check mark for the freerdp2 repository I had added. Since that time (almost a week now) I have not seen the request for credentials.  Take a look at your entries and try removing the check mark for any that are not default.